# after click the small window is open instaed of opning full activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

```
 main xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD CONTACT"
        android:id="@+id/btnadd"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
        android:onClick="addContact"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="VIEW CONTACT"
        android:id="@+id/btnview"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="viewContact"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Network Found"
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnview"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />
</RelativeLayout>





 main java file
    package com.example.dota.databasephp;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
    import android.net.NetworkInfo;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


        Button btnadd,btnview;
        TextView textView;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            btnadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
            btnview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnview);
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
            btnadd.setOnClickListener(this);
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            {
                textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
            else {
                btnadd.setEnabled(false);
                btnview.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Addinfo.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }


    }



addinfo xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_addinfo" 
    tools:context="com.example.dota.databasephp.Addinfo">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_name"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
        android:text="Enter Name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:text="Enter Email"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_name"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_name"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/et_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_mobile"
        android:text="Enter Mobile"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:inputType="phone"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SAVE DATA"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_mobile"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:onClick="saveInfo"/>

</RelativeLayout>


addinfo java file
package com.example.dota.databasephp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class Addinfo extends Activity {
    EditText Name,Email,Mobile;
    String name,email,mobile;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addinfo);
        Name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        Email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        Mobile=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_mobile);

        BackgroundTask backgroundTask=new BackgroundTask();
        backgroundTask.execute(name,email,mobile);
        finish();
    }
    public void saveInfo(View view)
    {
        name= Name.getText().toString();
        email=Email.getText().toString();
        mobile=Mobile.getText().toString();
    }

    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        String add_info_url;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            add_info_url="Domain_name/add_info.php";
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String name,email,mobile;
            name=params[0];
            email=params[1];
            mobile=params[2];
            try {
                URL url=new URL(add_info_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection= (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String data_string= URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"="+
                        URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"="+
                        URLEncoder.encode("mobile","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(mobile,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data_string);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return "One row of data inserted";


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }

}
```

After executing this code when I click on add contact button a very small box appears. What is that small box? I'm not getting why this box is appearing in execution. Please run the code, you will come to know what the problem is.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: that is the Toast which you have set in `onPostExecute`. Your questions is a huge dump of code which is quite wrong since most people would like a well formatted question. Poor questions like these are closed.

Comment: ok sorry fr the formate of code bt why it is not going to intent addinfo.class after clicking add contact

Comment: it is there. what makes you say it isnt ?

Comment: But I cnt view it .... only the small box is opened after clicking that addcontact button

Comment: please read how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are destroying your `Addinfo` activity by calling `finish()` in `onCreate()`.

Try removing this line:

```
finish();
```

from the `onCreate()` of your `Addinfo` activity.

Comment: thanx it worked fr me :P bt whts happened can u explain me plz

Comment: you should call finish() only when you manually want to destroy an activity